# sqlachemy UniqueConstraint with conditional?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to create a contraint on a table and specify a value on one or more of the columns? Condsider this example:

```
mytable = Table('mytable', meta,

    # per-column anonymous unique constraint
    Column('col1', Integer,),
    Column('col2', Integer),
    Column('col3', ENUM('ready', 'pass', 'fail'),

    UniqueConstraint('col2', 'col2', 'col3', name='uix_1')
    )
```

But I dont only want uniqueness when col3 is equal to something like a state of 'ready' (I WANT multiple success or failures).

```
    UniqueConstraint('col2', 'col2', 'col3 == ready', name='uix_1')
```

Is this possible in the sqlalchemy api?

Comment: If your database supports partial indexes, then yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976683/creating-partial-unique-index-with-sqlalchemy-on-postgres

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a full example on this [link](https://www.johbo.com/2016/creating-a-partial-unique-index-with-sqlalchemy-in-postgresql.html):

```
class ExampleTable(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'example_table'
    __table_args__ = (
        Index(
            'ix_unique_primary_content',  # Index name
            'object_type', 'object_id',  # Columns which are part of the index
        unique=True,
        postgresql_where=Column('is_primary')),  # The condition
    )

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    object_type = Column(Unicode(50))
    object_id = Column(Integer)
    is_primary = Column(Boolean)
```

so you can use something like this:

```
Index(
    'col1', 'col2',  # Columns which are part of the index
    unique=True,
    postgresql_where=Column("col3='ready'")),  # The condition
```

Comment: can one via `Index` with `unique=True` enforce unique together like via using `UniqueConstraint `?

Comment: I still able to add duplicated rows after adding this Index. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @MarkMishyn I think it's a database-level check. Are you sure you had this index (with `unique=True`) when you created the table? I recommend checking that this index is correctly exists in the table schema (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-describe-table).

Comment: @Mohsenasm thanks, I will check.

Comment: @Mohsenasm is this also possible for mysql?

Answer (score 1):

So from what I understand you want the group (col1, col2, col3) to be unique only if col3 has the value 'ready'?

I don't think that is possible using unique constraints. It could be done with a CheckConstraint, assuming your database supports it.

You can read up on it [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#check-constraint)